# C++ code formatter program (iterator not dereferencable)?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a C code formatter in C++,but I've stumbled across an issue.
I get a "string iterator not dereferencable" error.
The program doesn't compile unless the file is only about 2 lines long or I keep the insert() function in only one case.I've also tried converting string to char instead and incrementing an integer,but it didn't work with the string functions. Any solutions to this problem?Maybe there's a simpler way to make this program that I don't know about?Also I'm not that good at this.
Thanks in advance.

```
for (std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)

{
    switch (*it)
    {
    case '}':case '{':
    //  cout << *it << endl;
        if ((*it++) != '\n') {

            str.insert(it, '\n');
            cout << str;
        }
        break;
    case ';':
        if ((*it ++) != '\n')
            str.insert(it, '\n');
        break;
    default:


        while (parenthesis>0) {
            if (*it == '(')
            {
                parenthesis++;

            }
            else if (*it == ')') {
            parenthesis--;

            break;

            }//pos++;

        } 
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: if `*it` is ';', '{' or '}', what does `*it++` evaluate to? You have 30 seconds to come up with the answer, the clock is ticking...

Comment: It should return the next character from the string.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself, in  a debugger, and see if you're right (you're not).

Comment: I just did and that's what I've got after incrementing it.Although it's most likely wrong,since you're far more experienced than I am.I made a string consisting of "{h" and after the incrementation from '{' I got the letter 'h'.

Comment: No, you didn't. Whatever you did, either the value of `*it++` was not 'h', or you didn't print the value of `*it++`.   `*it++` is ***not*** "after the incrementation". I never said anything about where `it` points after `*it++`.

Comment: I got "{h{" in the file in the debugger I get 'h' '{' '\n' '{' '\0' after which it crashes.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're not evaluating `*it++`. If `*it` evaluates to '{', `*it++` will also evaluate to '{'. The code is `switch`ing on `*it`. Well, when the switch value is `{`, `*it++` will always be '{' also, so the comparison against a newline is utterly, completely, meaningless, because it will always be true.

Comment: So is there a way to iterate it within the switch?Or do I have to use a seperate variable for it?